# Unable to write to /var/log/btmp

Tags: permissions, ssh, logs

I recently had a bunch of entries in my btmp log [because of a boneheaded move on my part] I resolved the issue, but now I would like to clear that log, I copied it somewhere else for reference and then I attempted to null the file, but to no avail. I then checked the permissions for the file itself and everything looks right? Just unsure of why it will not let sudo access the file.

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo cat /dev/null > /var/log/btmp
-bash: /var/log/btmp: Permission denied
user@localhost:~$ ls -a -l /var/log/btmp
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp 5502336 Aug 20 18:59 /var/log/btmp
```

Just looking for some other ideas.. I tried changing the permissions and then changing them back just because. I also tried a few other ways to remove the text. But I want to figure out why this doesn't just work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command does not use sudo to write to the log file - it (unnecessarily) uses sudo to cat /dev/null. The writing (output redirection) via the `>` operator is still done as your regular user.

You can do either of the following

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/null > /var/log/btmp'
```

or

```
cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/log/btmp
```

however there's really no need to cat anything; you can truncate the file equally well simply by redirecting nothing to it

```
sudo -i
> /var/log/btmp
exit
```

or by using the `truncate` command

```
sudo truncate -s0 /var/log/btmp
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing response! I went ahead and ran:
    sudo truncate -s0 /var/log/btmp

Worked just as you explained. Would you mind explaining the -s0 switch? I presume that is what sets it to blank? Thanks again!